# Sending multiple cookies with same script

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to send two cookie values, one named "cookie1", the other named "cookie2" on a form submit. I had used the script below to capture one cookie and send it in a form. Now that I've added the second script which is identical to the first, only cookie2 is sent. Is this because I am using the same variable names in the javascript so only the last one gets saved or is it something else? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SubID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="addinfo" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(name) {
  var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
  return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
  var myForm = document.querySelector('form');

function handleSubmit() {
  var myHiddenInput = document.querySelector('[name=SubID]');
  myHiddenInput.value = getCookie("cookie1");
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, false);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(name) {
  var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
  return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
  var myForm = document.querySelector('form');

function handleSubmit() {
  var myHiddenInput = document.querySelector('[name=addinfo]');
  myHiddenInput.value = getCookie("cookie2");
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `<script>` totally overwrites the fist one. You do not have to declare the same functions and variables everytime:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SubID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="addinfo" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(name) {
  var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
  return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
  var myForm = document.querySelector('form');

function handleSubmit() {
  var myHiddenInput = document.querySelector('[name=SubID]');
  myHiddenInput.value = getCookie("cookie1");
  var myHiddenInput = document.querySelector('[name=addinfo]');
  myHiddenInput.value = getCookie("cookie2");
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using that script and it still overwrites the first value. I've also tried changing the 2nd variable to "myHiddenInput2" but still not working